# SWT hangs/freezes on Linux, when deployed as Java Web Start

Tags: java, swt

The Java WebStart application I am working on uses SWT for GUI, and I have recently realized a small but annoying problem. When I choose an action that uses a `FileDialog` i.e. save the image, the user interface freezes immediately after the dialog closes. 
The image is saved, and can be opened with a default image viewer without any problem, but the application is non-responsive from then on, and I am forced to kill the application.

I noticed that the result is the same when try to open a file using a `FileDialog`, if I instead open the same file by sending it as an argument by using the jnlp file, it works fine, so I don't think it's a problem with the local filesystem.

I have tried to replicate the problem on windows only to see that it works fine on Win 7. As a second attempt to troubleshoot, I tried to save an image from the local version of the application (in other words, non-JWS) and that works fine as well...

I was suspecting a permissions problem on the jnlp file, but all-permissions are given to the application, and signatures are all ok as well (the fact that the app starts points to that). Besides the image file is written anyways, so it can't really be a permission thing.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** It appears as there the problem doesn't only depend on FileDialog but any kind of graphical user interaction. Whenever SWT windows are deployed the program freezes with a gray screen, AFTER whatever action that was supposed to be done. I have copied some code below, in this particular example even if I click Cancel, the application becomes non-responsive with a gray screen. Here's some sample code:

```
    public static boolean saveChangesBeforeDiscard(MyMain main)
{
    if (main.isDirty())
    {
        MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(
            main.getShell(),
            SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.YES | SWT.NO | SWT.CANCEL);

        messageBox.setMessage("Would you like to save the changes?");
        messageBox.setText(MyMain.TOOL_NAME);
        int answer = messageBox.open();

        if (answer == SWT.YES)
        {
            SaveFileAction save = new SaveFileAction(main);
            save.run();

            return save.isSaved();
        }
        else if (answer == SWT.NO)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Update 2:** Btw I use Sun JDK 1.6.0. Here's the output of the java -version command:

> java version "1.6.0_22"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: @Dave: just added to the main text

Comment: Are you specifying full permissions in your webstart security policy?

Answer (score 3):

If SaveFileAction.run() takes a long time to run, that would explain the UI freezing.

In SWT, it is your responsibility to run the event pump.  Typically it looks something like:

```
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
```

But because SWT is also single-threaded, only one event is processed at a time.  So if an event listener takes a very long time to run, the UI will be unavailable until that listener finishes and control returns to the event pump.

When long-running operations are required, the recommended practice in SWT is to perform the operation in a worker thread, sending asynchronous updates to the UI as required.

```
executor.execute( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    showStatusMessage("Saving "+filename+"...");

    SaveFileAction save = new SaveFileAction(main);
    save.run();

    showStatusMessage("File "+filename+" saved.")
  }

  private void showStatusMessage(final String message) {
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec( new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        statusLine.setMessage(message);
      }
    } );
  }
} );
```

[This entry](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#uithread) on the SWT FAQ explains the threading model in more detail.

Comment: sorry for a very late reply, i was working on a manuscript when your answer came, and of course the holidays... Anyways, I sincerely thank you for the tips about the thread/process management with SWT, however your theory doesn't really explain why the GUI freezes even when the user escapes any action by using the Cancel button. In other words even if no action is executed after the window is deployed, the GUI hangs. If you have any suggestions to try out and narrow the crux of the problem, I will gladly poke around in the code :)

Comment: If your save action is a long-running operation and you are running it in the display thread, then it completely explains your UI hang.  In order for any action to be handled, including clicking on the cancel button, the display thread needs to be available to process events.  As long as your save action is running, the display thread is unavailable.  This is why it is so critical to execute long-running operations on any thread but the display thread.

Comment: interesting point, I need to dig into it a bit more and try it out a bit. By the way, do you have any idea why this would be a Linux specific problem, and not occur on windows systems?

Comment: It's possible it could be an issue with the Linux port.  A few questions though: have you moved the long-running operations to a non-display thread?  And you're not calling Thread.join() on any worker threads, right?

Comment: as far as I know there is no threading in this software, so I guess the answers are "no" and "no"...

Comment: In SWT, no threading + long running operation == UI hang.  Fork your work into another thread and watch the magic happen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in SWT that causes this:
[here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=280649)

The bug has recently been resolved - see the bug for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it appears as the bug mentioned in the link, and the solution provided there, applies to eclipse whereas I do not use eclipse for the JWS build. Further more, I have not had any problems on windows environment unlike the reported comments in the buginfo. Am I missing some link in between the problems?

Comment: The bug mentions the platform clearly as GTK. Also, whilst the title refers to a WebStart RCP plugin, the same underlying issue causes a freeze on any SWT/Linux/Webstart application. Test the integration build and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just  had a similar problem. I solved it by launching the `jnlp` file with IcedTea Java 6 Webstart (OpenJDK's `javaws`) instead of Oracle's `javaws`.